# VB.NET multithreading functions

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

So I've been working on a program that will find all files from a directory and subdirectories and my application is "freezing" while executing because its single-threaded, but I don't know how to multithread a function with an argument in it. so the use is like `getallfiles("C:/Folder")` and after this it will add each file in a listbox using the following code.

```
Private Sub getallfiles(filelocation As String)

        Try
            For Each item As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(filelocation)
                If Path.GetExtension(item) = My.Settings.scanfor & "filter" Then
                    Me.Invoke(Sub() ListBox1.Items.Add(item))
                    Me.Invoke(Sub() ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
                End If

            Next
            For Each folder As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(filelocation)
                Me.Invoke(Sub() getallfiles(folder))
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

and I'm trying to use `Thread1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf getcache(item))`

> Error BC30577 'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method
>   (without parentheses).

if you know any ways of fixing or doing this, I would be happy to hear your answer

Comment: You already know how to use a lambda expression, just use it as well for the thread.   Like New Thread(Sub() getallfiles(folder))

Comment: Show what `getcache(item)` is doing... More than likely your approach could be simplified much more just by looking at the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the vb file functions try the .net System.IO functions. With `Directory.GetFiles("Path of Directory to search", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` you can search with an extension filter as the second parameter and the last parameter will search all sub-directories. Don't add your items one by one to the listbox. That would be very slow because the listbox has to redraw on each iteration. The GetFiles function returns an array of Strings. You can add this all at once with the listbox items `.AddRange` Don't forget to add Imports System.IO at the top of the file.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Dim FilesFromDir() As String = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\maryo\Documents\TextNotes", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
ListBox3.Items.AddRange(FilesFromDir)
```

Comment: while this does work, it has trouble with system directories, even with full administrator privileges, upon encountering a system directory, it will just stop but that works and shortens the process by a lot thank you